# Website does not function after I edited content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently "made" a website for a friend and it stopped working after I edited some of the content. I don't know why the whole website is broken. It should have images and such...

Please take a look at the website and tell me if anything stands out to why it doesn't work. Thanks!

I have looked at all the html tags and they are all fine.

Comment: Please do not remove the original question from your post after it has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is opacity for `<article>` div is 0:

```
#main article{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

change to

```
#main article{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the opacity to 0 for all *ARTICLE* elements within your main *DIV*.  I see you have a transition setup for opacity, so I'm assuming you meant to either adjust that opacity value via a script or an animation.  Either way, until you implement such, remove the opacity style:

```
#main article {
  ...
  opacity: 0;
}
```